# Prove fingerprinting

Tags: randomness

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prove fingerprinting](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1692/prove-fingerprinting)

Let $a \neq b$ be two integers from the interval $[1, 2^n].$ Let $p$ be a random prime with $ 1 \le p \le n^c.$ Prove that
$$\text{prob}(a \equiv  b \pmod{p}) \le c \ln(n)/(n^{c-1}).$$

Hint: As a consequence of the prime number theorem, exactly $n/ \ln(n) \pm O(n/\ln(n))$ many numbers from $\{ 1, \ldots, n \}$ are prime.

Conclusion: we can compress $n$ bits to $O(\log(n))$ bits and get a quite small false-positive rate.

Comment: Since the question has been asked and answered on CS.SE, I'll migrate this copy there for it to be merged. Please note that [crossposting between multiple SE sites is highly frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068). Try one site first, and if you don't get a satisfactory response, ask a moderator to **migrate** the question to a different site.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Oh, I [thought this was more of a Math question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1692/prove-fingerprinting#comment4408_1692), but I hadn't realized it had already been posted on Math (otherwise I'd have closed the CS copy). Let's not complicate things further and leave the question where it is.